# Disable specific item from ngx-editor

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to disable a specific item from a ngx-editor but it does not work...

here is my actual code:

```
<app-ngx-editor [placeholder]="'Enter text here...'"
                     [enableToolbar]="true" [editable]="false"
                     [spellcheck]="true" [(ngModel)]="htmlContent"></app-ngx-editor>
```

When I set "editable"="false", all item of toolbar are disabled... How can I disable only the "video" buttom?

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem. I find solution

```
<app-ngx-editor  [config]="editorConfig" [placeholder]="'Enter text here...'" [spellcheck]="true" [(ngModel)]="content"></app-ngx-editor>
```

and inside your Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-job-offer',
  templateUrl: './new-job-offer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-job-offer.component.css']
})
export class NewJobOfferComponent implements OnInit {
    content = '<h1>Hello2</h1>';
    editorConfig = {
        editable: true,
        spellcheck: false,
        height: '10rem',
        minHeight: '5rem',
        placeholder: 'Type something. Test the Editor... ヽ(^。^)丿',
        translate: 'no',
        "toolbar": [
            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strikeThrough", "superscript", "subscript"],
            ["fontName", "fontSize", "color"],
            ["justifyLeft", "justifyCenter", "justifyRight", "justifyFull", "indent", "outdent"],
            ["cut", "copy", "delete", "removeFormat", "undo", "redo"],
            ["paragraph", "blockquote", "removeBlockquote", "horizontalLine", "orderedList", "unorderedList"],
            ["link", "unlink", "image", "video"]
        ]
    };


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

please, remember add [config]="editorConfig" to your  app-ngx-editor in your html code.

In toolbar section is possible to disable some useless icon ;)

Comment: config property is not recognized anymore:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-editor-3c5bdc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: yes, because this solution work correct for Angular 6. When I change my app for Angular 9 config property is not recognized. In the future i will check why... but in this moment i am working on other part my app.